# Analytics in System Administration

Tags: android, mobile, analytics

How does the term "analytics" translate in terms of system administration?
Are there analytics packages for Android, if you wanted to gather usage data within a mobile application?

Comment: Are you asking about Google Analytics? http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Yes...About Google Analytics

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has good support for [Android devices](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/) and have a [easy guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4) to getting started.

Comment: Can you please answer briefly :

Comment: How does the term "analytics" translate in terms of system administration?